# Prolog recursively append the list

Tags: prolog

Here's a code which recursively add the element X at the end of the list.

```
app(X, [], [X]).
app(X, [Y | S], [Y | S2]) :- app(X, S, S2).
```

Could anyone explain me how it works? Where's the return statement, what exactly the `app(X, S, S2)` `[Y | S], [Y | S2]` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need return statement everything is done by unification (simply pattern matching). The clause:

```
app(X, [Y | S], [Y | S2])
```

states that the second argument is a list with head Y and tail S and the third argument is a list with head Y and tail S2. So it forces (by using unification) the heads of the two lists to be the same. Recursively the two lists become identical except the fact that the third argument list has one more element in the end (element X) and this is defined by the first clause. Note that second clause only works for lists with one or more elements. So as a base of the recursion when we examine the empty list (in the second parameter) then the third list due to first clause contains only one more element the element X.

Answer (score 2):

Prolog programs are made by defining facts and rules. You define facts and rules, and Prolog interpreter tries to come up with solutions to make them true. Other than this basic concept, you need to know two other important concepts which Prolog programmers use extensively.
These are:

1. Input and Output parameters: There are no return statements in Prolog. Some variables will be results (outputs) and some others will be the inputs. In your program, the first and second parameters are input and the last one is the output.
2. Pattern Matching: If a list is expressed as `[Head|Tail]`. Head is the first element and Tail is a list of the remaining elements.

When you call `app`, for example, as `app(5, [1, 2, 3, 4], L).`, Prolog interpreter tries to come up with values for `L` such that `app` is true.

Prolog interpreter is solving the problem in the following steps:

1. In order to make `app(X, [Y | S], [Y | S2])` true, the first element of the last parameter need to become `Y`. So, in my example, L becomes [1, S2].
2. Then it tries to match the rule `app(X, S, S2)`. Here S is [2, 3, 4] and S2 is the output parameter for the next run. Then Step 1 gets repeated but with `app(5, [2, 3, 4], S2)` and after that `S2` becomes [2, S2]. So, `L`, now, becomes [1, 2, S2].
3. This same thing gets repeated (recursion) and `L` is populated as [1, 2, 3, 4, S2].
4. Now, the second parameter is empty. So, the first fact `app(X, [], [X])` is matched. In order to make this true, the last parameter becomes a list containing just `X` (which is 5 in this case), which results in `L` being [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

Answer (score 0):

Prolog newbie here. I tested the code for the app predicate over there. As far as I can see it's not working as a proper append predicate. I'd propose:

app([], Y, Y).

app([X|S], Y, [X | S2]) :- app(S, Y, S2).

Hope the comment is not too stupid. The two answers given above seem to cover properly the question of the post, so no comment about that.